How to disable APIPA from CLI on XUbuntu
I'm trying to disable APIPA on my Wi-Fi interface.
I found this nmcli command but it does not work :
$ nmcli con modify sebWlan ipv4.link-local disabled
Error: invalid property 'link-local': 'link-local' not among [method, dns, dns-search, dns-options, dns-priority, addresses, gateway, routes, route-metric, route-table, routing-rules, ignore-auto-routes, ignore-auto-dns, dhcp-client-id, dhcp-iaid, dhcp-timeout, dhcp-send-hostname, dhcp-hostname, dhcp-fqdn, dhcp-hostname-flags, never-default, may-fail, required-timeout, dad-timeout, dhcp-vendor-class-identifier, dhcp-reject-servers].
$ nmcli con modify sebWlan ipv4.link-local 2
Error: invalid property 'link-local': 'link-local' not among [method, dns, dns-search, dns-options, dns-priority, addresses, gateway, routes, route-metric, route-table, routing-rules, ignore-auto-routes, ignore-auto-dns, dhcp-client-id, dhcp-iaid, dhcp-timeout, dhcp-send-hostname, dhcp-hostname, dhcp-fqdn, dhcp-hostname-flags, never-default, may-fail, required-timeout, dad-timeout, dhcp-vendor-class-identifier, dhcp-reject-servers].
$ nmcli -v
nmcli tool, version 1.36.6
$

Although it is well documented here.
Is there another way ?
